# Catching non-terminating errors in calculated properties

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I generally set `ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` in my PowerShell scripts and use `Trap` and/or `Try...Catch` to detect non-terminating errors, but for some reason, this error seems to be un-catchable.

The `[datetime]'13/12/2016'` expression in the script below causes an 'Invalid Argument Runtime Exception', but the `try...catch` is not triggered, despite having `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`.

```
$Error.Clear()
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$a = @( "name", @{name='test';expression={([datetime]'13/12/2016')}} )
try {
    Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ | Select-Object -Property $a
} catch {
    Write-Host "Caught error: $($_)"
}
write-host "There were $($Error.Count) error(s)"
write-host "Most recent error: $($Error[0] | out-string)"
```

To be clear, I'm NOT interested in fixing the datetime conversion, I know how to do this, but I DO want to understand why I cannot catch the error.

I have tried this in PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0 environments.

UPDATE: If I add a line `[datetime]'13/12/2016'` in the `Try` block, this DOES trigger the `Catch`.

UPDATE: Adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Get-ChildItem` and/or `Select-Object` cmdlets makes no difference.

Comment: `Select-Object` swallow errors occurred in property expressions.

Comment: Can this behavior be altered, @PetSerAl ?

Comment: I do not know ways to do that, but, of course, it does not mean, that them do not exist.

Comment: You have to use `-ErrorAction` Stop for this case because it is for that particular line specific.

Comment: I did try that, @RanadipDutta, but it made no difference.

Comment: ok. Let me try. Actually , when I ran your script  in PSVersion 5. Then It is not going to catch block since both the lines are not throwing any error by logic . Powershell backend is not able to handle and storing it in $error. That is the reason, I am able to see the count also. Lets see how to get a catch

Comment: My only approach at the moment is to check for an increase in `$error.count`, and then `throw $error[0]`